# How to use @ngrx/router-store inside feature module

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

In the [NGRX documentation for Router-Store](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/router-store/README.md), they only provide an example with `.forRoot()`. When I tried using `.forFeature()` I discovered that no such static method exists.

I would like to be able to define certain actions & effects for use within my feature module (and the app module as well).

How does one go about using router-store inside of feature modules?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set it up for feature modules. You only need to set it up once by `StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot()` in your `app.module.ts`, that's enough.

Comment: If I'm defining actions and selectors at the app module level and using them in a feature module, then this is a bad design, is it not?

Comment: @ManPersonson This is out of the scope of the question. However, FYI, that's a bad design IMO. Each feature module should have its own actions and reducer. See the example app here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app

You should follow the smart component dummy component as well.